# Regular expression for repeating sequence with inserted word

Tags: python, regex

I have regex to match repeating sequence of word 'abc' separated by spaces.

```
re.search("(abc+\s){3}", "abc abc abc ")
```

I want to upgrade it to match sequences with 0 or 1 inserted words(words can be different with different lengths).
Examples:

```
"abc abc abc " #match
"abc defgh abc abc " #match
"abc xyz abc abc " #match
"abc abc ghi abc " #match
"abc ghi abc def abc " #not match
```

Number of repetitions may also vary, it should be applicable to multiple repetitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a quantifier for the pattern to specify the number of repetitions for free (possible multiple) matches, it can be difficult to set an end boundary to determine when then match stop and when is it considered not valid any more.

For example, you can check that there is not an "other" word in between 2 `abc`  strings, but one of the difficulties is that when having a lot of words that can occur multiple times as well.

What you might do is use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) with regex.finditer and make use of the captures collection that can count the number of occurrences of a named capture group.

If the number is 0 or 1, then there is at max 1 other word than `abc`  in the match and the match is valid.

In the pattern, if you want to match the word 3 times, you can set the quantifier at the end to `{2}` as the pattern starts with the first match:

```
\babc (?:(?P<word>(?!abc )\w+ )?abc ){2}
```

- `\babc`  Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?P<word>` Named group "word"

    - `(?!abc )\w+`  Negative lookahead, assert not `abc`  to the right and match 1+ word chars
  - `)?` Close named group and make it optional
  - `abc`  match literally
- `){2}` Close the non capture group and repeat n times (here 2 times)

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wb6d3Y/1) (Note that you do not see the multiple capture groups here as `re` does not support captures) and see a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##bVHbasMwDH33V2h@slkotN0FQrt8wcbe1zHSxEkMjW1sh7Zr@@2ZnabOxiwQHB356AhLHW0jxbLveauktqBZzQ4IqdxapgWsQePNNt8WQLKUZO@rvdTlC8nuPEU3@3ug2QBPiwtGxmouauNUHwhcYN@6JU4mrmRV3UQ7h@N3lPdZN/wff@PcxKjGp2XGzkMF50Au/jwJxXkqPVgG9BC18J3HgJ4CeobfS8QSo0@EKqnBABcw/l46TPfsVwJtbovGN5noWqZzy8hwoVnFRcndich4qQQMpVepD17BjgkyyGdFrmynmSHYXw9TCqs1zKfHPpTztqTCr4Ohc0/hdFXXWnaK0AumQcB2hsXlb3JcOT6h738A)

Example code:

```
import regex

pattern = r"\babc (?:(?P<word>(?!abc )\w+ )?abc ){2}"
strings = [
    "abc abc abc ",
    "abc defgh abc abc ",
    "abc xyz abc abc ",
    "abc abc ghi abc ",
    "abc ghi abc def abc ",
    "abc abc abc test1 abc abc  | abc test2 abc abc test abc abc | test abc test3 abc test4 abc ",
    "abc abc test5 abc test6 abc test7 abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc "
]

for s in strings:
    for _, match in enumerate(regex.finditer(pattern, s)):
        if len(match.captures("word")) <= 1:
            print(f"Match for: {match.group()}")
        else:
            print(f"No match for: {match.group()}")
```

Output

```
Match for: abc abc abc 
Match for: abc defgh abc abc 
Match for: abc xyz abc abc 
Match for: abc abc ghi abc 
No match for: abc ghi abc def abc 
Match for: abc abc abc 
Match for: abc test2 abc abc 
No match for: abc test3 abc test4 abc 
Match for: abc abc test5 abc 
Match for: abc test7 abc abc 
Match for: abc abc abc 
Match for: abc abc abc
```

**Note** that in the loop, the `match` variable is a [Match Object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) holding the information about the match which might come in handy for after processing.

---

There is a same sort of solution using Python `re` and split on a space. Then you can count the number of splitted parts, but you would have to calculate the threshold based on the allowed number of parts.

Then using the previous code, you can change

```
pattern = r"\babc (?:(?:(?!abc )\w+ )?abc ){2}"
```

And

```
for match in re.findall(pattern, s):
    if len(match.split(" ")) < 6:
        print(f"Match for: {match}")
    else:
        print(f"No match for: {match}")
```

[See a Python demo](https://ideone.com/7by0fc)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex to match:

```py
\b(?!(abc +(?!abc )\w+){2})(?:abc +(?:\w+ +)?){3}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UZ8GbP/5)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?!(abc +(?!abc )\w+){2})`: Fail the match if there are more than one non-`abc` words
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `abc +`: Match `abc` followed by 1+ spaces
  - `(?:`: Start inner non-capture group

    - `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
    - `+`: Match 1+ space characters
  - `)?`: End inner non-capture group. Match this group 0 or 1 times
- `){3}`: End outer non-capture group. Repeat this group 3 times

Comment: I was looking at the examples given in the question, but I think the last line should not match right?

Comment: I think (but that is just guessing) that if you have 3 occurrences of abc, there can be max 1 occurrence of another word in between.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: I have modified my answer. Hope it is right now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/abc+\s(([a-z]+\sabc)|(abc\s[a-z]+)|abc)\sabc+\s/
```

Comment: You don't need the `/` as delimiters in Python. Can you add a bit of  explanation to the pattern for the OP and future readers?

Comment: One issue with this is that this is not scalable. What if the ask is to match 10 occurrences of `abc` ?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you're looking for is `(abc\s)(?:(?:\1\1)|(?:\w+\s\1\1)|(?:\1\w+\s))`

```
import re

pattern = r"(abc\s)(?:(?:\1\1)|(?:\w+\s\1\1)|(?:\1\w+\s))"

bool(re.search(pattern, "abc abc abc "))  # True
bool(re.search(pattern, "abc defgh abc abc "))  # True
bool(re.search(pattern, "abc xyz abc abc "))  # True
bool(re.search(pattern, "abc abc ghi abc "))  # True
bool(re.search(pattern, "abc ghi abc def abc "))  # False
```